# Does giving two tasks the same name cause problems

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to run two jobs which have the same name. I set the names of the job to be same initializing

```
mapreduce.job.name
```

Does this cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

it may be reassigning the value on the second declaration... Would have to see code to tell..
but in general naming convention you want to stay away from that... Not only because of issues your running into but for readability for yourself and others that may be working on the same project

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer... **NO**

The name you provide is for human eyes only. The jobs are executed by job id... doesn't matter how many jobs has same name. However, as a practice the Job names should uniquely identify the job so that when you are looking up a job and intend to kill it, you don't end up killing wrong job.

Also please modify your question...you can name a Job **not** Task